# Wix Installer - Custom prompt, using what’s entered during install

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.7

I am new to using Wix, but I have been able to install my windows service fine what has no UI prompts currently, but I have now been asked to allow custom installations. What I mean by this is they want us to prompt the customer for a text entry like company name, and then we use this in the install directory e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\Company Name and also for the Windows service to have this e.g. MyApplicationWindowsService – Company Name.

Answer (score 0):

It's vary big and general question. I suggest you to start with some tutorials on how to customize the UI.

For Example:  [Tutorial 1](http://www.merlinia.com/mdt/WiXTutorial3.msl), [Tutorial 2](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/02/07/add-custom-dialogs-wix-installer/).

After trying to implement your customize UI with no luck, you can post a new question with specific details and your snippet code.